# pg_database_size() is small,but pg_dump is very big

Tags: postgresql

I faced a strange question.
when I use the psql command " \l+ db_name" or following sql,

```
cattle_dev=# \l+ cattle_dev                                        
                                                    List of databases
    Name    |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges |  Size   | Tablespace | Description 
------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------------
 cattle_dev | cattle_dev | UTF8     | zh_CN.UTF-8 | zh_CN.UTF-8 |                   | 1738 MB | pg_default | 
(1 row)

cattle_dev=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('cattle_dev'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 1738 MB
(1 row)

cattle_dev=#
```

it tells that the database is small.
But,if i use the pg_dump to backup this database,the result is too large,it's almost 18GB.

```
[enterprisedb@ppasdev 20170605012443]$ ll -h cattle_dev_20170605012443.dmp 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 enterprisedb enterprisedb 18G Jun  5 01:34 cattle_dev_20170605012443.dmp
[enterprisedb@ppasdev 20170605012443]$
```

The problem is why the pg_dump result is too large,but the pg_database_size is small?

any help would be appreciated.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of them is the binary size on disk. PostgreSQL compresses on disk all TOASTable fields over 2k (like text). Think about a binary value: they usually represent less space on disk than the same value `CAST`ed to text anyway.

```
SELECT b::text, pg_column_size(b) AS on_disk, length(b::text) AS text
FROM ( VALUES (now()) ) AS t(b)
UNION ALL 
  SELECT b::text, pg_column_size(b), length(b::text)
  FROM ( VALUES (49839489::int) ) AS t(b)
UNION ALL
  SELECT b::text, pg_column_size(b), length(b::text)
  FROM ( VALUES ('192.168.43.58'::inet) ) AS t(b);
               b               | on_disk | text 
-------------------------------+---------+------
 2017-06-05 20:56:45.978472-05 |       8 |   29
 49839489                      |       4 |    8
 192.168.43.58/32              |      10 |   16
(3 rows)
```

In addition, you're going to have overhead merely because the SQL, schema, and input format (being CSV or whatever).

You may want to look into the `-z` option. (Or, `xy` if you need the best compression).

```
-Z 0..9
--compress=0..9
  Specify the compression level to use. Zero means no compression. For the custom archive format, this specifies compression of individual table-data
  segments, and the default is to compress at a moderate level. For plain text output, setting a nonzero compression level causes the entire output file
  to be compressed, as though it had been fed through gzip; but the default is not to compress. The tar archive format currently does not support
  compression at all.
```